# Getting missing pandas error while trying to fine-tune GPT3

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, fine-tuning

I'm using the following command :
`openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f ./data.jsonl`

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Analyzing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jyothiraditya/mambaforge/bin/openai", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/jyothiraditya/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py", line 63, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/Users/jyothiraditya/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/cli.py", line 586, in prepare_data
    df, remediation = read_any_format(fname)
  File "/Users/jyothiraditya/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/validators.py", line 477, in read_any_format
    assert_has_pandas()
  File "/Users/jyothiraditya/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/datalib.py", line 56, in assert_has_pandas
    raise MissingDependencyError(PANDAS_INSTRUCTIONS)
openai.datalib.MissingDependencyError: 

OpenAI error: 

    missing `pandas` 

This feature requires additional dependencies:

    $ pip install openai[datalib]
```

I tried reinstalling `datalib` using : `pip install --upgrade openai openai"[datalib]"` but it did not work

I tried install pandas manually : `pip install pandas` but it also did not work

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command:

```
pip install openai[datalib]
```